# changing item values after grouping with linq

Tags: c#, linq

its hard to explain, but I try.

I did a linq grouping.

`var grouping = aList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Width, x.Height, x.Quantity});`

Lets say I have 3 groups now in grouping. Group 1 has 1 item, group 2 has 5 items and group 3 has 9 items.
All items are having a "stack" field. What I want to do now is, set a number into the stack field of each item based on the group.

All items in group 1 should have the same "stack" number lets say "1", all items in group 2 should have the same "stack" number, maybe "2" and all items in group 3 should have the same "stack" number. So, one "stack" number per group.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is a query and is not meant to modify an existing object.  So if you want to modify existing without creating a new then use code below

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<MyList> aList = new List<MyList>() {
                new MyList() { Width = 1, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 1, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 1, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 2, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 2, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 3, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 3, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 3, Height = 2, Quantity = 3},
                new MyList() { Width = 3, Height = 2, Quantity = 3}
            };

            var grouping = aList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Width, x.Height, x.Quantity });

            int number = 0;
            foreach (var group in grouping)
            {
                foreach (MyList myList in group)
                {
                    myList.StackNumber = number;
                }
                number++;
            }

        }

    }
    public class MyList
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int StackNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort, but I commented the same "double foreach" solution on the first answer a couple minutes ago. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you should have initialized `number` at `1` or incremented before assigning.

Comment: @NetMage : Does it matter the stack numbers start at zero or one?

Comment: @jdweng Apparently to the OP it did: `All items in group 1 should have the same "stack" number lets say "1"`

Comment: @NetMage : Not a requirement.  The OP said "lets say".

Comment: The "1" was just an example. Like I said, I had the same solution minutes after posting the question. In my case it doesn't matter which number. I get multiple data rows to this method and put them into a list with items that already have stack numbers. I use the highest and increment. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` has another overload that passes the index number to the delegate, you could use that.

```
var grouping = aList
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Width, x.Height, x.Quantity});
    .Select( (x,y) => new { Item = x, Stack = y } );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I already had a solution, but I forgot to iterate on the right line. I did it like this 


foreach (var group in grouping)
{
   foreach (var row in group)
   {
        row.StackNr =  stackNr;
        allStacks.Add(row);
   }
stackNr++;
}